# Prototype in Javascript code confusion

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
}

// Greeting
Person.prototype.greeting = function() {
  return `Hello there ${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
}



// Customer constructor
function Customer(firstName, lastName, phone, membership) {
  Person.call(this, firstName, lastName);

  this.phone = phone;
  this.membership = membership;
}

// Inherit the Person prototype methods
Customer.prototype = Person;

let detail1 = new Customer("hom", "kom", 989, "l");
detail1.greeting() //  it is producing error that greeting is not a function
```

Why when I am running detail1.greeting() is producing an error even though I have set the prototype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Customer.prototype = Person;` won't tie a `Customer`'s methods to `Person.prototype`'s methods, because the methods aren't on `Person` itself, but on `Person.prototype`. While you *could* do `Customer.prototype = Person.prototype`, that's probably not desirable, because then mutations to `Customer.prototype` would affect `Person.prototype` as well.

For `Customer.prototype` to inherit `Person.prototype`'s methods, you should have `Customer.prototype` be an object whose internal prototype is `Person.prototype`, which can be done with `Object.create`:

```
Customer.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

```js
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
}

// Greeting
Person.prototype.greeting = function() {
  return `Hello there ${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
}



// Customer constructor
function Customer(firstName, lastName, phone, membership) {
  Person.call(this, firstName, lastName);

  this.phone = phone;
  this.membership = membership;
}

// Inherit the Person prototype methods
Customer.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);

let detail1 = new Customer("hom", "kom", 989, "l");
console.log(detail1.greeting()) //  it is producing error that greeting is not a function
```

Comment: Or, since the question is tagged ecmascript-6, just use the `class` and `extends` declarations and let the interpreter handle it for you.

Comment: @CertainPerformance how mutations to customer.prototype would affect Person.prototype??

Comment: @Alex_Angular: The same way as in `var foo = {}; var bar = foo; bar.baz = 42;`. Objects are reference-type values.